# POSTMAN How to parse a nested json object in postman which has dynamic keys?

Tags: json, postman

supposing the json body returned from a call contains some dynamic keys ie

```
{
     "message": "search results matching criteria",
     "permission": {
         "261ef70e-0a95-4967-b078-81e657e32699": {
             "device": {
                 "read:own": [
                     "*"
                 ]
             },
             "account": {
                 "read:own": [
                     "*"
                 ]
             },
             "user": {
                 "read:own": [
                     "*"
                 ]
             }
     }
}
```

I can validate the json as follows easily enough although I am having a lot of trouble working out how to validate the objects BELOW the dynamic guid level of the response.

```
pm.test("response body to have correct items", function () {
pm.expect(jsonData.message).to.eq("search results matching criteria");
pm.expect(jsonData).to.have.property('permission');
pm.expect(jsonData.permission).to.have.property(pm.variables.get("otherUserId"));
```

});

Would ideally like to verify the device and account and user levels of the object.

Anyone with some tips?

I've tried a few ways to try and reference the otherUserId variable but nothing is working. It is either not resolving the variable therefore failing the test as its looking for a level in the json called otherUserId or it fails to run the test due to a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
pm.expect(jsonData.permission[pm.variables.get("otherUserId")]).to.have.property('device');
```